# Get all config files with spring cloud config

Tags: spring, cloud, gitlab, config, spring-cloud-config

I am relatively new to spring cloud config and I am able to pull the config file with the application name. There is a need for me to pull all the config files from Git via Spring Cloud Config without having to know or pass the application name in the context.

Currently I have used "spring.cloud.config.server.git.searchPaths= *" in my bootstrap file to search my entire git project and using "/{application}-{profile}.properties" to pull the properties files matching the application file. Would want to pull all properties files without passing this application name, is this possible?

I would require this logic to know how many properties files are checked in and how many are duplicates and this logic will be handled by my custom REST service that I am planning to write.